Problems with LVE ID 5487
I made a php application that uses the spatie library top convert pdf files to jpg, using ghost script and imagickMagic.
The process is slow, but in dev environment, it works fine. I just adjusted the max_time_execution in php.ini (I use xampp) and tádááá! It works fine with big and complex pdfs. Takes time, but it goes. But not in production
I changed the max_time_execution, post_max_size, memory_limit to its maximum and still I get this error message:
[Thu Jul 25 10:46:54.558135 2024] [lsapi:error] [pid 27229:tid 140211220608768] [client 181.222.135.68:54373] [host myhost.com] Error on sending request(GET /phpfile.php?file=teste.pdf HTTP/1.1); uri(/phpfile.php?file=teste.pdf) content-length(0): ReceiveAckHdr: nothing to read from backend (LVE ID 5487), check http://docs.cloudlinux.com/mod_lsapi_troubleshooting.html, referer: http://mydomain.php

The server is at it´s full capacity and the application is really simple: Here is the code:
    $pdf = new Spatie\PdfToImage\Pdf("$path".$file);
    $numberPfpages = $pdf->getNumberOfPages();
    $j = 1;
    for ($i=0; $i < $numberPfpages; $i++) {
      $fileName = $path."página_".$j;
      $pdf->setPage($j)->saveImage($fileName.".jpg");
      $j++;
    } 
  }

So, in this loop, the file is paged and the pages are converted to jpg, so the user can read the pdf page by page, in jpg format. It allows better user experience, like marking pages and make comments about the pages. This was the way I found to have all these features in my application.
I don´t know what is the problem with the server, and how to configure it properly, so it run with any pdf that I choose to upload and read.

Please [edit] the title of your question to be descriptive, unambiguous, and specific to what you are asking. For more guidance, see How do I write a good title?.

How many pages does this involve? Maybe running this as a background job is better?

It seems the error message you’re encountering on your server is related to issues with the LiteSpeed API (lsapi) and the server is at full capacity.
In this regard you might try to amend php.ini config on your server (if you have access to it) like:
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 300
memory_limit = 512M
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
max_file_uploads = 20

For LiteSpeed you can try adjust the number of children and max requests, like:
LSAPI_CHILDREN=50
LSAPI_MAX_REQUESTS=5000

And last but not least, try to process PDF pages in batches:
<?php
    $pdf = new Spatie\PdfToImage\Pdf("$path" . $file);
    $numberPfpages = $pdf->getNumberOfPages();
    $batchSize = 10; // Process 10 pages at a time
    $j = 1;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $numberPfpages; $i += $batchSize) {
        $end = min($i + $batchSize, $numberPfpages);
        for ($k = $i; $k < $end; $k++) {
            $fileName = $path . "pagina_" . $j;
            $pdf->setPage($j)->saveImage($fileName . ".jpg");
            $j++;
        }
        // Optional: Pause or flush the output to free up resources
        sleep(1);
        flush();
    }
?>

Hope that works for you!

Please note that Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned and read Help Center: AI policy. It is not permitted to use AI tools to generate or reword content that you post on Stack Overflow.

To mitkosoft: it didn´t work out. Thanks any way for the help. Still the same error message.
